# How i can match this regex?

Tags: php

I have make my own router so i need to match or get data from url

```
router(array('GET', 'OPTIONS'), '^/player/check/(.*)$', function() {
    // Enable CORS
    enableCORS();
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo 'asd';
});
```

Where i can match or get Data from (.*) ?
Such `$username =` ?

Comment: and the framework would be?

Comment: @smith non-framework